# SPI to classic Bluetooth

Tags: spi, bluetooth

I have an embedded system with SPI interface.
I need to send file of 400-500 KB to a smartphone so I was thinking to use a Bluetooth board with SPI interface (because of file dimension I would like to use classic BT instead of BLE).
I found only BLE boards with SPI interface or classic BT board but with serial interface (limited to 115kbs).

Is there any reason why these board are not available?
Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason why these board are not available?

Nobody asks for these? Someone who has to transfer large amounts of data usually needs something that allows for some custom protocol logic. People who just want serial-over-Bluetooth don't want to transfer large amounts of data. (this has something to do with the fact that the recovery mode for what to do when a part of the transmission was not successful are different)

> Any suggestion to solve this problem?

As usual: put another microcontroller in it. In your case, some of the newer ESP32s, maybe? That has an SPI interface, enough RAM to buffer in both directions, and does bluetooth in all relevant variations.